# Adb protocol fault (couldn't read status)

Tags: android-studio, adb, osx-elcapitan

I am using Mac OSX El Captain with Android Studio 2.2.

Android Studio start to don't show Android devices suddenly. I try to kill adb server and start it again and this errors appear on terminal.

> List of devices attached
>
> - daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
>
> adb E  1165 84563 usb_osx.cpp:307] Could not clear pipe stall both ends: e0004051
>
> adb E 1165 84563 usb_osx.cpp:289] Could not find device interface
>
> - daemon started successfully *

When I try to kill server twice for understanding the issue it gives this error message:

> error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Connection reset by peer

Comment: make sure to use `platform-tools` v24.0.4. the previous version had a USB related regression

Comment: Im using platform tools v24.0.4

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting your Mac and devices. I ran into a similar error and restart got rid of it :)